# Reading from scanner and skipping whitespace

Tags: java, parsing, split, java.util.scanner, csv

This program is working okay when my input file does not include initial white space. I need it to work ok when the input file lines have space in the beginning. Here an example of my input:
This works:

1. Window "Calculator" (200, 200) Layout Flow:

This does not work:

1. < 4 spaces here>      Window "Calculator" (200, 200) Layout Flow:

I think it is because in the working sample, it will scan and place the word in the string at array place 0. The second one does not work I think because it is places blank space in array place 0. I used a split \\s+ to avoid space in my code but it doesn't seem to solve this problem. How can I make this scanner skip all initial white space and skip the white space in between the words in the input file, while placing the first word in array space 0;

code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Parser {
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int c = 0;
        boolean pane = false;

      File input = new File("input.txt");

      try{

          Scanner reader = new Scanner(input);
          do{

              String[] buff2 =  reader.nextLine().split("\\s+");

          for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){
              System.out.println(buff2[0]);
              if(buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("end")){
                 c = 4; 
                 frame.setVisible(true);    
              }
              if(! reader.hasNextLine() ){
                 c = 4; 
                frame.setVisible(true); 
              }

              if(buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("window")){

                    frame = new JFrame(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-1));
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setSize(Integer.parseInt(buff2[2].substring(1, buff2[2].length()-1)),Integer.parseInt( buff2[3].substring(0, buff2[3].length()-1)));
//                  frame.setVisible(true); 

                    if (buff2[4].equalsIgnoreCase("Layout")){
                      if (buff2[5].subSequence(0, buff2[5].length()-1).equals("Flow")){
                      frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                      }
                      else if (buff2[5].equalsIgnoreCase("grid")){
                        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(Integer.parseInt(buff2[6].substring(1, buff2[6].length()-1)),Integer.parseInt(buff2[7].substring(0, buff2[7].length()-1))
                                ,Integer.parseInt(buff2[8].substring(0, buff2[8].length()-1)),Integer.parseInt(buff2[9].substring(0, buff2[9].length()-2))));
                      }
                    }
                }

              if (buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
                 if (pane == true)  {
                     panel.add(new JLabel(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));
                 }
                 else frame.add(new JLabel(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));

                }

              if (buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("button")){         
                  if (pane == true) {
                     panel.add(new JButton(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));
                 }  
                  else frame.add(new JButton(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));

                }

              if (buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Textfield")){          
                  if (pane == true) {
                     panel.add(new JTextField(Integer.parseInt( buff2[1].substring(0, buff2[1].length()-1))));
                 }  
                  else frame.add(new JTextField(Integer.parseInt( buff2[1].substring(0, buff2[1].length()-1))));


                }

              if (buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("panel")){

              pane = true;
              frame.add(panel);
              String layout = (String) buff2[2].subSequence(0, buff2[2].length()-3);


                  if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("Flow")){
                  panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                  }



                  else if (layout.equalsIgnoreCase("grid")){
                      System.out.println("hi");
                    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(Integer.parseInt(buff2[2].substring(5, buff2[2].length()-1)),Integer.parseInt(buff2[3].substring(0, buff2[3].length()-1))
                            ,Integer.parseInt(buff2[4].substring(0, buff2[4].length()-1)),Integer.parseInt(buff2[5].substring(0, buff2[5].length()-2))));
                  }

                }

              if (buff2[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Label")){
                 if (pane == true)  {
                     panel.add(new JLabel(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));
                 }
                 else frame.add(new JLabel(buff2[1].substring(1, buff2[1].length()-2)));

                }




          }
          }
          while (c !=4);
          }



        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("invalid file");
        }

      }
    void group(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) the line before splitting it.

```
String[] buff2 =  reader.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method trim from the class String.
Trim removes any leading (and trailing) whitespaces.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html